# show Field values in upperCase in Crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my Crystal Report, I want to show the Field values in Upper Case.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 25):

You don't need to create a separate Formula Field to achieve this result.

Instead, add the following to the field's Display String conditional formula:

```
UpperCase(CurrentFieldValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go ... http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=8823

You will notice in this example they are using the `UpperCase` function of Crystal Reports. So, all you need to do is say `UpperCase(`***some field name***`)` and that take care of it for you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way, if the link ever goes down, your answer would still be useful to others!